# order a sequence based on the sum of the window values

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, if-statement

I know the question is not very clear so I try to make a clearer example:
I have some values, which represent the minute of the day and a corresponding value, like

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1440)
values = np.sin(2*np.pi/1440*2*l - np.pi/2)+1
```

and I want to get the ordered (from lower to larger) sums per hour of `values`, where I don't want any value to be excluded, except at least the highest remaining ones, so in this case I would get 24 ordered (my hours) values, or better 23 if I consider that the minimum sum could be anywhere in the series and in the end I will have some values at the end and the beginning whose 'window will be less than 60 minutes, except in a very particular case.

I don't know if I should apply a boolean mask in a while loop which I could manage to do or if numpy or some other packets have already some functions that could help me in solving the problem. Thanks

Also, if possible, I would like to get the SORTED NONSUBSQUENT SUMS, up to the moment where I have no more intervals of the right (WINDOW) length, which in this particular case implies that my results will have a minimum of 12 windows sums up to 24. Thanks again

So, in a general case (I have no space to insert the minute data) if my values are: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,7,8,9]` and I will need to group them in windows of 3 elements size (in the real case this is my 60 minutes window), my result will be:
`[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

Or to be more general,if they are: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,7,9,1,9,6]`, in the first case I would get: `[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,9,1]]` (because I take subsequent windows) and in the second case I would get: `[[0,0,0],[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[1,9,6]]` (because I just focus on the minimum sorted sums)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to have a rolling window or if you want to sum over full hours. Here is the first try, by reshaping the values into a 24 x 60 array to get sums for the full hours.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(60*24)
values = np.sin(2*np.pi/1440*2*x - np.pi/2)+1

x_values = values.reshape((24, 60))
sums = x_values.sum(axis=-1)
print(np.argsort(sums))
# array([12,  0, 11, 23, 13,  1, 10, 22, 14,  2,  9, 21, 
         15,  3,  8, 20, 16,  4,  7, 19, 17,  5, 18,  6])

# if some values are missing / not yet available you can simply 
# fill them with zeros
values[3, 16:] = 0  # no data available for 04:16 - 05:00
values[3, :] = 0  # or ignore this hour completely
```

## EDIT

Some remarks after the clarifications:
As always it depends on your use case which of the two options are better for you, maybe you even want to allow some overlap between the hours...

It seems a little strange to me to order everything after the first minimum you find; I would prefer the option where the intervals can be placed arbitrarily over the day, but note that you can easily end up with less than 23 valid intervals in this case.

```py
inf = 1e9
m = 3
a = np.array([1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,7,9,1,9,6])

for i in range(len(a)//m):
    b = np.convolve(a, v=np.ones(m), mode='full')
    i = np.argmin(b[m-1:-m+1])
    if inf in a[i:i+m]:
        break

    print(i, a[i:i+m])
    a[i:i+m] = inf

# This gives you the intervals with the corresponding starting index
# 8 [0 0 0]
# 0 [1 0 1]
# 3 [2 3 4]
# 13 [1 9 6]
```

For completeness here is also the second option:

```
# get interval with minimal sum
b = np.convolve(a, v=np.ones(m), mode='full')
i = np.argmin(b[m - 1:-m + 1])

# reshape values and clip boundaries according to found minimum i
a = a[i % m: -((len(a)-i) % m)]
a = a.reshape(-1, m)

# order the intervals and print their respective indices in the intial array
i_list = np.argsort(a.sum(axis=-1))
print(a[i_list])
print(i%m + i_list*m)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 9 1]]
# [ 8  2  5 11]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want to get... I need to start at the MINIMUM POSSIBLE ITERVAL OF 60 MINS.. Your solution simply takes the sums every hour, but this is not what I need, Thanks again.

Comment: Once I got the FIRST MINIMUM WINDOW, I have 2 choices: 1) to check ALL previous and following  windows and order them; 2) to repeat the algorithm and find the next (not subsequent) 2nd MINIMUM INTERVAL and so on.... I don't know if I have been clear enough

Comment: So to get this straight, if your data collection starts at 15:23, you want to set this time as start of hour 0 and count from there? And if you collect data until 15:11 the next day you want to skip the last incomplete hour?

Comment: Maybe add a simple example with 4 hours per day and 5 minutes per hour to demonstrate what you mean, because I can't quite follow you

Comment: I have no problems with start and end times, I just want to sort my values from the minimum sum up to the highest, so just think that every 24 h starts and ends at midnight... Maybe I just need to loop over all possible intervals with ```np.argsort()```?

Comment: Thank you so much, do you have any clues for the first case instead? Because I need to confront the 2 results based on the fact that "jumping" between intervals pays a penalty. Otherwise I will manage somehow. Thanks again